# Changed locales to en_US.UTF-8 but program still tries to translate to other language

Tags: debian, apt, locale, unattended-upgrades

I change the systems locale settings to `en_US.UTF-8` with `dpkg-reconfigure locales`. The `locale` command outputs:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

In `/etc/default/locale` I have the following content:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Also, `/etc/locale.gen` does contain only `en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8`.

Running `unattended-upgrades` every morning from `/etc/cron.daily/apt-compat` produces the following errors in my syslog:

```
apt.systemd.daily[3829]: --- Logging error ---
apt.systemd.daily[3829]: Traceback (most recent call last):
apt.systemd.daily[3829]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 983, in emit
apt.systemd.daily[3829]:     stream.write(msg)
apt.systemd.daily[3829]: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xfc' in position 43: ordinal not in range(128)
apt.systemd.daily[3829]: Call stack:
apt.systemd.daily[3829]:   File "/usr/bin/unattended-upgrade", line 1538, in <module>
apt.systemd.daily[3829]:     main(options)
apt.systemd.daily[3829]:   File "/usr/bin/unattended-upgrade", line 1219, in main
apt.systemd.daily[3829]:     logging.info(_("Allowed origins are: %s"), allowed_origins)
apt.systemd.daily[3829]: Message: 'erlaubte Urspr\xfcnge sind: %s'
apt.systemd.daily[3829]: Arguments: (['origin=Debian,codename=stretch,label=Debian-Security'],)
```

The system tried to translate `Allowed origins are: %s` to the german version `erlaubte Ursprünge sind: %s`, which contains a special char `ü`. After some research I found out, that the file with the translations is found here: `/usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/unattended-upgrades.mo`.

Why does `apt` / `unattended-upgrades` tries to translate english to german, as I have changed the locales already to the correct english values? How can I stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem by issuing the following commands again:

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
localectl set-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LANGUAGE=en_US:en
```